# converted web site to web application, works without namespaces

Tags: asp.net

I converted a web site project to a web application using this guide

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

In the guide it says that I have to add namespaces to my classes but I did not do that. The classes I have in the `Old_App_Code` directory are not placed into namespaces and the application runs just fine (tested on different machines). Is it because there is something special about `Old_App_Code` or am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misinterpreting what the guide is saying, it is NOT saying that you need to add namespaces to get the code to compile, but rather that the conversion process does not add the namespaces into the code files by using the folder/file naming constructs.

The guide is further underscoring the fact that when you add new items (i.e. classes) in a web application versus a web site; the namespace is automatically added to the code file, based upon the folder structure and file name of the of new class.